# Java Comp Sci nested loops to find closest fraction

Tags: java, loops, nested

I want to find the closest fraction equal to 16/76. Whenever i run this i get 1 no matter what. I am doing this for Java class in school.

```
public class ClassOne {
public static double limit = 16/76;
public static double difference = 1;
public static double numer = 1;
public static double denom = 1;
public static void main(String[] args)
{




  for(int i = 1;i<=100;i++)
{
    for(int x = 1;x<=100;x++)
{
double temp = limit-(double)(x/i);
System.out.println((x/i));
if(Math.abs(temp) < difference && x/i != 16/76){difference = temp;numer = x; denom = i;
System.out.println("hi");}
}
}
    System.out.println(numer +  " " + denom);

}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean, "The closest fraction to 16/76?"  16/76 _is_ a fraction.  It happens to be the same fraction as 8/38 and 4/19.

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering integer division here:

```
limit - (double)(x/i)
```

...and here:

```
public static double limit = 16/76;
```

Both `x` and `i` are `int`.  The cast here will take effect *after* the division operation has taken effect.

Change your cast so that it applies immediately to one of the variables instead:

```
limit - ((double)x)/i
```

Also, consider wherever else you're doing any quotient that isn't with a floating point number (i.e. has a decimal after it or is explicitly cast to a `double`) - if you need it to be a floating point number, then use the appropriate cast.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems

1. Use (double)x/(double)i where needed - probably assign to a temp
2. difference=temp should be difference=Math.abs(temp) or put the abs on the original temp computation
3. x/i = 16/76 is subject to floating point errors and so may not be hit when you want.  May want to use something like 16*i != 76*x which can be computed in integers.  I get 21 100.